# Efficient way to sum overlapping date intervals with several groupings in PostgreSQL version 8.4

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum

Hello I'm new to stackoverflow and relatively new to psql so please be lenient if I do things wrong.

I have a large data set showing animal movements that looks a little like this:

```
animalid | movementdate | offmovementdate | location | rsk
==========================================================
1        | 1998-01-01   | 1998-04-01      | 3        | Y
1        | 1998-04-01   | 1999-04-01      | 1        | Y
1        | 1999-04-01   | 1999-07-01      | 2        | N
2        | 1998-05-01   | 1999-04-01      | 3        | Y
3        | 1998-02-01   | 1999-01-01      | 2        | N
3        | 1999-01-01   | 1999-06-01      | 1        | Y
4        | 1997-12-01   | 1998-05-01      | 1        | Y
4        | 1998-05-01   | 1999-04-01      | 2        | N
```

I want to sum all the contact days of an animal (i.e. in a location shared by another animal) stratified by risk. The intervals are movementdate-offmovementdate. The variable lcd should sum the number of days spent on the same location with another individual. So if I spent 3 days in the same place as 2 people and 2 days in the same place as 1 person my lcd is 3+3+2=8.

So my output should look something like this:

```
animalid | rsk | lcd
=======================
1        | Y   | 120
1        | N   | 0
2        | Y   | 0
3        | Y   | 90
3        | N   | 245
4        | Y   | 30
4        | N   | 245
```

Thus the value 120 in the first row is obtained by adding the overlapping intervals for locations 3 (0 days) and 1 (1999-01-01 to 1999-04-01 + 1998-04-01 to 1998-05-01).

I have tried the following queries:

```
CREATE TABLE tmpcpy AS
SELECT ta.animalid,ta.location,ta.rsk,
   SUM(AGE(LEAST(ta.offmovementdate,tb.offmovementdate),
   GREATEST(ta.movementdate,tb.movementdate))) ctc_ds 
FROM tmpd ta, tmpd tb 
WHERE ta.location=tb.location 
  AND ta.animalid IS DISTINCT FROM tb.animalid
  AND LEAST(ta.offmovementdate,tb.offmovementdate) > 
      GREATEST(ta.movementdate,tb.movementdate)
GROUP BY ta.animalid, ta.rsk, ta.location;

CREATE TABLE lcd_out AS 
SELECT animalid, rsk, SUM(ctc_ds) lcd 
FROM tmpcpy 
GROUP BY animalid, rsk;
```

But I get the following error message.

```
ERROR:  could not write block 24905954 of temporary file: No space left on device
```

Is there a more efficient way of getting the desired output?

The output of explain for the first query with my real dataset is the following:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=677015920636.46..691909507980.53 rows=3804913 width=42)
->  Sort  (cost=677015920636.46..679994626690.54 rows=1191482421630 width=42)
Sort Key: ta.animalid, ta.rsk, ta.location
->  Merge Join  (cost=18773271.33..71508531671.51 rows=1191482421630 width=42)
Merge Cond: (ta.location = tb.location)
Join Filter: ((ta.animalid IS DISTINCT FROM tb.animalid) AND (LEAST(ta.offmovementdate, tb.offmovementdate) > GREATEST(ta.movementdate, tb.movementdate)))
->  Sort  (cost=9646734.67..9741857.48 rows=38049124 width=26)
Sort Key: ta.location
->  Seq Scan on moves ta  (cost=0.00..1214663.24 rows=38049124 width=26)
->  Materialize  (cost=9126536.67..9602150.72 rows=38049124 width=24)
->  Sort  (cost=9126536.67..9221659.48 rows=38049124 width=24)
Sort Key: tb.location
->  Seq Scan on moves tb  (cost=0.00..1214663.24 rows=38049124 width=24)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide more insight into how the numbers are calculated?  Where does "120" come from for the first row of the table, for instance?

Comment: The output of `explain analyze` or at least of `explain` for both queries would also be helpful

Comment: You should explain what is the criteria to determinate overlapping dates: number of days in the same location of at least one other animal? MOVE and DEATH columns are not considered in this extraction? MOVEMENTDATE and OFFMOVEMENTDATE are the interval delimiters?

Comment: OK I have edited the question I hope it's clearer. I will look into adding explain analyze

Comment: What is the meaning to have rows with null for OFFMOVEMENTDATE and LOCATION?

Comment: They were deaths but I have removed them because they are not relevant to the question. Thank you for your patience as previously mentioned I am new at this.

Comment: You join all rows with overlapping dates for each location which results in a huge intermediate result set (estimated rows: 1,191,482,421,630). I can only think of one way to avoid the "no more space", running the query multiple times with chunks of data, e.g. `ta.animalid between 1 and 1000`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion dnoeth. Do you mean run the query for a limited number of animals and store the resulting number of contact days in a new column, e.g. tmp_ctc, and then contact days for the next set of animals will be estimated as before + tmp_ctc? Or is there a better/faster way of doing that?

Comment: The query I provided in my answer is much faster. I don't know if there may be one yet faster. Give it a try!

Comment: Thanks I'm currently going through it and changing it so it matches my actual data headings etc. I will let you know the outcome as soon as I have it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how to treat those records with OFFMOVEMENTDATE and LOCATION null I can give you this query(it should be a little more efficient because it doesn't perform an expensive self join) that simply ignore those rows:

```
with act_data (animalid, movementdate, offmovementdate, move, location, death, rsk) as (
        values(1, date'1998-01-01', date'1998-04-01', 1, 3, 'f', 'Y')
        union all
        values(1, date'1998-04-01', date'1999-04-01', 2, 1, 'f', 'Y')
        union all
        values(1, date'1999-04-01', date'1999-07-01', 3, 2, 'f', 'N')
        union all
        values(1, date'1999-07-01', cast(null as date), 4, cast(null as integer), 't', 'N')
        union all
        values(2, date'1998-05-01', date'1999-04-01', 1, 3, 'f', 'Y')
        union all
        values(2, date'1999-04-01', cast(null as date), 2, cast(null as integer), 't', 'N')
        union all
        values(3, date'1998-02-01', date'1999-01-01', 1, 2, 'f', 'N')
        union all
        values(3, date'1999-01-01', date'1999-06-01', 2, 1, 'f', 'Y')
        union all
        values(3, date'1999-06-01', cast(null as date), 3, cast(null as integer), 't', 'N')
        union all
        values(4, date'1997-12-01', date'1998-05-01', 1, 1, 'f', 'Y')
        union all
        values(4, date'1998-05-01', date'1999-04-01', 2, 2, 'f', 'N')
        union all
        values(4, date'1999-04-01', cast(null as date), 3, cast(null as integer), 't', 'N')
    ), my_data as (
        select row_number() over() as id,t.*
        from act_data t
    ), dates as (
        select movementdate as day
        from my_data
        union
        select offmovementdate
        from my_data
    ), my_intevals as (
        select day as start_int, lead(day) over(order by day nulls last) as end_int
        from dates
        where day is not null
        order by day nulls last
    ), intervals as (
        select row_number() over(order by start_int nulls last) as interval_id, start_int, end_int, end_int - start_int as duration
        from my_intevals
    ), overlapping_intervals as (   
        select rsk, location, interval_id, start_int, end_int, duration, array_agg(animalid) as animals
        from intervals i
            join my_data d on (i.start_int>=d.movementdate and i.end_int<=d.offmovementdate)
        group by rsk, location, interval_id, start_int, end_int, duration
        having count(*) > 1
    )
select a as animalid, i.rsk, sum(i.duration) as lcd
from overlapping_intervals i
    cross join unnest(animals) a
group by a, i.rsk
order by animalid, i.rsk
```

It returns your excepted output

```
 animalid | rsk | lcd
----------+-----+-----
        1 | Y   | 120
        3 | N   | 245
        3 | Y   |  90
        4 | N   | 245
        4 | Y   |  30
```

**UPDATE**

To perform the same extraction on 8.4 without using the cross join on the array column you can use the following script. Switch references to my_data with the name of your main table and if you already have locations table in your environment use it in place of the evaluated one. It re-executes over the distinct locations the same query to populate a temp table in several steps. You can also commit at the end of each loop to check if execution time is acceptable.

```
create table my_data (animalid, movementdate, offmovementdate, move, location, death, rsk) as (
    values(1, date'1998-01-01', date'1998-04-01', 1, 3, 'f', 'Y')
    union all
    values(1, date'1998-04-01', date'1999-04-01', 2, 1, 'f', 'Y')
    union all
    values(1, date'1999-04-01', date'1999-07-01', 3, 2, 'f', 'N')
    union all
    values(1, date'1999-07-01', cast(null as date), 4, cast(null as integer), 't', 'N')
    union all
    values(2, date'1998-05-01', date'1999-04-01', 1, 3, 'f', 'Y')
    union all
    values(2, date'1999-04-01', cast(null as date), 2, cast(null as integer), 't', 'N')
    union all
    values(3, date'1998-02-01', date'1999-01-01', 1, 2, 'f', 'N')
    union all
    values(3, date'1999-01-01', date'1999-06-01', 2, 1, 'f', 'Y')
    union all
    values(3, date'1999-06-01', cast(null as date), 3, cast(null as integer), 't', 'N')
    union all
    values(4, date'1997-12-01', date'1998-05-01', 1, 1, 'f', 'Y')
    union all
    values(4, date'1998-05-01', date'1999-04-01', 2, 2, 'f', 'N')
    union all
    values(4, date'1999-04-01', cast(null as date), 3, cast(null as integer), 't', 'N')
);

create table locations as (
    select distinct location
    from my_data
    where location is not null
);

create local temp table tmp_result_table (
    animalid bigint,
    location bigint,
    rsk text,
    lcd bigint
) ON COMMIT preserve ROWS;


DO $$DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT location FROM locations
    LOOP

    insert into tmp_result_table(animalid, rsk , lcd)
        with dates as (
                select movementdate as day
                from my_data d
                where d.location = r.location
                union
                select offmovementdate
                from my_data d
                where d.location = r.location
            ), intervals as (
                select start_int, end_int, end_int - start_int as duration
                from (
                        select day as start_int, lead(day) over(order by day nulls last) as end_int
                        from dates
                        where day is not null
                    ) a
            ), overlapping_intervals as (   
                select rsk, start_int, end_int, duration, array_agg(animalid) as animals,
                    count(*)-1 as factor
                from intervals i
                    join my_data d on (i.start_int>=d.movementdate and i.end_int<=d.offmovementdate)
                where d.location = r.location
                group by rsk, start_int, end_int, duration
                having count(*) > 1
            )
        select unnest(animals), rsk, lcd
        from (
                select rsk, animals, sum(duration*factor) as lcd
                from overlapping_intervals
                group by rsk, animals
            ) a;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;$$



select animalid, rsk, sum(lcd) as lcd
from tmp_result_table
group by animalid, rsk
order by animalid, rsk desc;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It works perfectly up to and including the overlapping_intervals subquery. But unfortunately at 'unnest(animals) a' I get an error message saying that the column animals doesn't exist. If I change it to '(select unnest(animals) a from overlapping_intervals) ta' lcd becomes 240 for all individuals with rsk 'Y' and 490 for 'N'. In other words it just sums up all the overlaps within risk. If it makes any difference I am running PostgreSQL version 8.4 as mentioned in the title.

Comment: I'm far from my db now and I'm not fully familiar with postgre's versions, but have you tried using I.ANIMALS?

Comment: Yes it says that I'm not allowed to use it for the cross join, same as when you join a table with itself you give each one a different alias.

Comment: I provided a query that does the same without the cross join on the array column

Comment: Thank you very much Alessandro. Your query now works with the test data set. However, when I did 'explain' with my full dataset I noticed that the query would involve temporary tables that are 320 times longer than the one that @dnoeth identified as causing the memory problem. So I would like to ask for some general guidance now regarding stackoverflow etiquette because I very much want to thank Alessandro for his time and effort. I can't upvote yet and I'm wondering whether I should tick his answer because the original query also works with the test data set...

Comment: Don't worry about it. I'd just like to know if you can extract OVERLAPPING_INTERVALS  subquery without having performance issues with your full data

Comment: Well I have been running the full query for the last 21 hours and it hasn't crashed so far. I'll let you know when something happens.

Comment: I would stop it. I also noticed that your original query won't evaluate a correct value when three or more animals share the same location, so I updated my answer with a different method. The needed temp space should be a fraction of the first one

Comment: I've just checked my original query with a slightly larger test set where 3 or more animals can share the same location and it gave the correct output. I appreciate that this could be a fluke because the test set is so simple and so for pedagogic ereasons I really would like to know what situation you foresaw that would cause it to go wrong and why. That being said, I'm going to have a crack at your new solution now and I'll let you knowthe out come when I have it. Also thanks again I feel like I'm really learning a lot from these conversations.

Comment: You can see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/18bcb/1 tree animals sharing a 90 days interval get 180 days because time is summed for every other animal in the same location not only once. You told me you were looking for "number of days in the same location of at least one other animal"

Comment: 180 days is the desired output as the animal is on the location with 2 other animals for 90 days each. Thus 90+90=180 (cf 2nd paragraph in original question). This is important because lcd will then be divided by the total number of days spent in a (non)risk are to give the average group size for that animal per time spent in a (non)risk area.

Comment: Ok, I updated the query to give this output, but did the new script execute fine. What is the size of the data you are analyzing and in what range are the intervals distributed(min start date max end date and average interval length)?

Comment: There are approx. 38 million rows, interval length can vary from a day to several decades and the whole table spans almost a century. Group size is also highly variable ranging from a handful to hundreds of individuals. It might take me a bit longer to respond now but rest assured that I'm still looking into your answer. As mentioned before I really appreciate the time and effort you have put into helping me witth this problem.

Comment: Hello. Sorry for taking so long to reply. Unfortunately the method you propose to do the loop is not compatible with 8.4. I have tried to test your code by looping the query in R with Rpostgres but it appears that it would take 5-6 months to run. I am therefore pursuing a completely different approach which involves estimating the herdsize at each location for each time point. I have now ticked your answer because it does solve the memory issue. Thanks for all your help.